# Marking a selected Zeppelin Column as link

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Below is my query:

```
%psql.sql
select text from delta limit 5;
```

Is it possible to display text as the link in Zeppelin?

Answer (score 0):

Try transform your text column, like

```
%html <a href="[LINK_ADDR]">[TEXT]</a>
```

Take a look http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/displaysystem/basicdisplaysystem.html#table for more information.

Comment: I saw that example but how would you rewrite the query in that case or what if there are multiple columns and you want only one of the columns to be link_addr?

Comment: i think you can rewrite query something like this - 

```select concat("%html <a href='", link_column, "'>", text_column, "</a>" * from table```